# Tag feed: New commend doesn't update the 'updated' field

Tags: feature-request, tags, feed

I'm trying to build a notification service that tracks some stackoverflow tag and push updates to some API

let's say we have the following feed url:

https://stackoverflow.com/feeds/tag/quickblox

What I noticed is that if a user provides some comment to question (not answer) then the 'updated' field of entry wasn't updated.
So I don't know how to understand that some user provided a comment to answer.

Do you have any ideas?

Comment: Well, you can screen-scrape. Other than that, I'm not aware of *any* mechanism for this. Second-class citizens, etc, etc, etc.

Comment: @NathanTuggy you mean to check each entry's page and screen scrap? Well, yes, it's a possible solution, but not optimal